# Is there a way to force or maintain the aspect ratio of a window when resizing it?

Tags: windows, video, window, aspect-ratio

I have certain windows like VLC for example that I'd like to be able to resize without them losing a 16:9 ratio.  This would be useful for image viewers too.  And just plain functionality would be awesome to have.  I am sure there's a program out there to do it, but what is it?

Comment: For VLC at least you can use the Z key to resize the window in steps according to the size of the video. That will keep the window in the correct AR.